# snort rule: logging access to site containing the word "Malware"

Tags: snort, intrusion-detection

I am trying to create a rule for snort to basically log any packets once a user tries to access a page with the word "malware" in it. This is what I have, just asking for some guide. So basically once a webpage contains the phrase it shows an alert.

```
 alert tcp any any -> any any
 (content:"malware";
  msg:"Someone clone is accessing a page with malware tagged!!!!";
  aid:10000002;rev:1;)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alert tcp any any -> any any (content:"malware"; msg:"Someone clone is accessing a page with malware tagged!!!!"; aid:10000002;rev:1;)

Actually worked and the problem was solved